# Aggregate interactive brokers data in matlab

Tags: matlab, interactive-brokers

I am using matlab and interactive brokers API. I am getting real time data using

tickerID = ib.realtime({ct},'233',@(varargin)ibEventRealTimeData(varargin{:}));

where ib is the interface to interactive brokers TWS Activex object and ct is the contract.

I am getting all the events (ticksize, tickprice and so on) but I can't aggregate data/prices (for example, in 5 minute bars). What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't aggregate"? Any error message?

Comment: If you've got tick data, can't you just generate quantized data using, e.g., the time series object?

Comment: Hi Wisentgenus. I mean something similar to  the data provided by this example, but in real time:


d = timeseries(ib,ibContract,startdate,enddate,barsize,ticktype) requests Interactive Brokers aggregated intraday data for a specific type of market data tick ticktype.

Comment: DMitri, could you please give me a hint on how do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure Java library with Matlab examples for getting daily and minute aggregated bars. It is based on IB Java API. I wrapped it to have a simple interface:

http://www.spreadvectors.com/wisentgenus#code

IB has limitations when requesting historical data:

- Making identical historical data requests within 15 seconds.
- Making six or more historical data requests for the same Contract, Exchange and Tick Type within two seconds.
- Do not make more than 60 historical data requests in any ten-minute period.

Comment: +1: Also, recall that there is a max of 50 messages per second being sent to and from TWS. See https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/order_limitations.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to aggregate the 5-min bars, you need to add code within your `ibEventRealTimeData` function that remembers the previous values (possibly using a `global` or `persistent` variable) and appends the new data to it.

If you do not need realtime info, you could make a single request for 5-min historical data. But here too, IB sends the results in separate events that you would need to aggregate within your callback.

As an alternative you could use the [IB-Matlab product](http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/IB-Matlab), which connects IB and Matlab, and aggregates the information for you, in both the historical/intra-day request and the realtime bars request.